# Oracle SQL REGEXP_SUBSTR - return values from string

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to extract some data from a string in Oracle. I think I need to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, but I'm struggling with this.

Example string:

```
Retirement , Cost , Book : BUFFALO CA GAAP , Asset Period : Jul-23 , Asset Number : 26294 , Transaction Number : 285454
```

From this example string I am trying to extract the string *following* Book :, Asset Period :, and Asset Number :.

I'd like to return the following strings in separate columns.

```
BUFFALO CA GAAP
26294
285454
```

Can someone help with this?

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(xal.DESCRIPTION,'[^_]+',1,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ',\s*Book\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*,', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS book,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ',\s*Asset Period\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*,', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS asset_period,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ',\s*Asset Number\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*,', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS asset_number,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ',\s*Transaction Number\s*:\s*(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
         AS transaction_number
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Retirement , Cost , Book : BUFFALO CA GAAP , Asset Period : Jul-23 , Asset Number : 26294 , Transaction Number : 285454' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BOOK | ASSET_PERIOD | ASSET_NUMBER | TRANSACTION_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BUFFALO CA GAAP | Jul-23 | 26294 | 285454 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/E7n-YLca)

Comment: MTO thank you so much!! Exactly what I was looking for.  Can you explain to me what this part is doing ',\s*Asset Number\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*,', 1, 1, NULL, 1? I would really appreciate that!!